# How to bypass or skip CustomFilter in Mockito with springboot applicaiton

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I am using springboot appllication and mockito for testing. So below are some files and code samples.

```
public class CustomerInfoFilter extends GenericFilterBean
{

    @Override
    public void doFilter (ServletRequest request,
                          ServletResponse response,
                          FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException,
        ServletException
    {
        Customer customer = (Customer)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        // some more logic 

        // call next filter in the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
     }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()........... some logic
    }

    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomerInfoFilter(customerInfoDao), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // Some logic
    }
}
```

Below is piece of code written in Mockito test :

```
@Test
public void verifyCustomerInfoUnauthorized () throws Exception
{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/customer").contentType(
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{}").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(
            status().isUnauthorized()).andExpect(status().is(401));
}
```

- Now as you can see in SecurityConfig class CustomerInfoFilter will be called after BasicAuthenticationFilter.
- Because the way that test is written is failing since it's not sending any authentication details.
- And piece of code : `Customer customer =(Customer)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();` is failing with NullpointerException because off-course we are not passing authentication details in the test and getAuthenticaiton() will return null. 

  Question: How can I skip this custom filter in mockito.? In other words how can disable this custom filter only during testing.?
   Or any other workaround or tricks.?

Sorry I am new to spring and mockito :) any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show us how do you bootstrap your test?

Comment: @Haim Raman Sorry I didnt get you ?.... I am running a Junit test.

Comment: Is this a plain Junit or @SpringBootTest

Comment: @HaimRaman . it marked  as ```@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest```

Comment: and how do you setup your mockmvc

Comment: this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).dispatchOptions(
            true).addFilters(filterChainProxy).build();

Comment: Did not had time to check, but maybe this will help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests

Answer (score 2):

```
@Mock
SecurityContext context;

@Mock
Authentication auth;


@Mock
Principal principal;

@Test
public void verifyCustomerInfoUnauthorized () throws Exception
{

    when(context.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(auth);
    when(context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/customer").principal().contentType(
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{}").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(
        status().isUnauthorized()).andExpect(status().is(401));
}
```

You can do something like above or set the mocks directly in the test method. Either way it should do the trick. The most important piece is the `.setContext()` piece. That's where your null pointer is coming from.

I find this is the cleanest way to go about it.